# How to permutation index view for weights and input nodes for a layer? TensorFlow/numpy

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

Let's say I have a permutation index:

```py
pa = [2,0,4,3,1,5] # node permutation index
pw = [0,3,4,1,2,5] # weight permutation index
a = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
w = np.array([0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2]
```

I want semantics that resemble this:

```
ap = a[pa] # [0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6]
```

except that instead of a copy, I want a view. That is, I want:

```
ap[0] = 0.123
assert(a[2] == 0.123)
```

I don't think numpy has this concept. But wondering if there is a way to make this happen in  TensorFlow.

I want this concept in TensorFlow for arbitrary weight sharing. I need the weight sharing to be pre-defined by an arbitrary index because each target node will have a different ordering of the same set of weights, and apply these weights to an arbitrary subset of the input layer. The weight must be referenced through the permutation so that back-propagation will modify all instances of the same weight.

Comment: Note re application: this is somewhat related to weight sharing in a convolutional neural net. However, unlike a CNN the pattern of weight sharing will not reduce to any typical slicing operation. So I want a permutation like a[pa] that is a view the way a slice is a view.

Comment: If TensorFlow can't do this, is there another ANN system that can?

Comment: You mention that numpy does not have this concept - which I think is correct - but you could consider doing all your computations on a copy `ap`, then reassigning back to `a[pa]` when you finish

Comment: That won't work. I need to give this to TensorFlow as a layer, so I don't really have direct control of when values get modified. Changes to a[pa] must be reflected in all instances of the original (and there would be a large number of instances). If it were actually a view, this would work. Also, the copy operation would utterly kill performance. So I really do need view semantics rather than copying. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Link to a more graphic description: https://www.yknotlabs.com/gameofy/weight_sharing/